# TorButton Warning and SSL

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration, browsers, ssl, noscript

A little new to Tor, been taking a closer look at how requests happen in the browser. At the top when I open Tools >> Web Developer >> Browser Console and start browsing the web I notice a few things:

1. I get this TorButton warning every few seconds:

   ```
   "Torbutton WARN: no SOCKS credentials found for current document."
   ```

Can anymore tell me what this means and if it's critical?

2. Also noticed a lot of this when browsing to sites with DigiCert SSL certificates:

   ```
   "getFirstPartyURI failed for http://ocsp.digicert.com/: 0x80070057"
   "getFirstPartyURI failed for http://clients1.google.com/ocsp: 0x80070057"
   "getFirstPartyURI failed for https://safebrowsing-cache.google.com/safebrowsing/rd/..."
   ```

And this for sites using LetsEncrypt SSL:

```
    "getFirstPartyURI failed for http://ocsp.int-x3.letsencrypt.org/: 0x80070057"
```

Can anyone tell me what this means? And why it might be failing?

3. In NoScript >> Advanced >> HTTPS >> Behavior, it's possible to force SSL everywhere. I kinda like this idea. I'm considering adding "*.*" so force SSL on every website. Sure, many sites still don't support SSL but likewise HttpsEverywhere doesn't apply SSL to some sites that support it. So I'm kinda in the middle here. Would anyone recommend against forcing SSL everywhere? This might make my tor traffic more identifiable in some way, right?